# Pip installation is failing on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7

"sudo easy_install pip" fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==18.5', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Users/swastika.singhal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/swastika.singhal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/swastika.singhal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2408, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/swastika.singhal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2414, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 46, in <module>
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import ensure_directory, ContextualZipFile
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

The Google solutions did not work for me so far.

Comment: just use brew instead

Comment: See if there is any help in [this github issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/252). Are you using the python distribution that comes pre-installed on Mac? Instead of homebrew you can also use macports.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. This GitHub issue helped me fix it: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub issue helped me fix it: github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169

Specifically:

There are lines in mysql_config like following:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

I edited them to:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Comment: Could you please add a brief explanation of what you did to fix your problem? Link-only answers are not well received on StackOverflow.